# Get Eureka to respect order of Eureka servers specified in serviceUrl mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I would like my Eureka client to attempt to register with a Eureka server, where there is a list of potential Eureka servers. This list is purposely ordered in my application.yml in the serviceUrl mapping:

```yaml
    eureka:
      instance:
        non-secure-port: 80
        secure-port: 443
        secure-port-enabled: true
      client:
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: https://server-a.com, https://server-b.com, https://server-c.com, https://server-d.com
```

I'd like it to behave such that after failing to register with A, it moves onto B second, and so on.

Based on what actually happens (setting RestTemplate to DEBUG), and looking at the Eureka source code, the list is being randomized.
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/efc1cf6017f13f5f2491838bde894630a37dfd75/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/discovery/shared/resolver/aws/ZoneAffinityClusterResolver.java#L69

This is what actually happens:

```
    o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://server-b.com/apps/
    o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://server-d.com/apps/
    o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://server-c.com/apps/
    o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://server-b.com/apps/
    ....
```

This continues. While I'm sure there is a reason this is done randomly, this is not desired for my use case. Is there a way to avoid this randomization via configuration of some sort?